# How to set extra bold to text in string resources?

Tags: android, html, android-layout, android-studio

I have a question is there a way to set text the extra bold weight in a string resource?

this is what I have now:

```
<string name="home_text2>
<![CDATA[
some text<br/>
more text<br/>
<b>even more text</b>\u1433
]]>
</string>
```

The designer says all text should be in bold not just as i have it now in example string. which is easy setting android:textStyle="bold" in the text view. But how do I set part of the text in the example string as extra bold?

Been more specific I want to set the extra bold weight to the part of the text that now is just bold.

Thanks!

Comment: What is "extra bold"?

Comment: @CommonsWare with extra bold i mean set the font with a weight higher than bold, i think in html is "bolder"

Answer (score 1):

Nothing involving string resources or `TextView` support "extra bold" out of the box. You are welcome to try creating a custom `CharacterStyle` that implements "extra bold" by some means. Or, use a `WebView`. Or, draw text directly to a `Canvas`, with painting rules that implement "extra bold".